# ShareActionProvider appearance

Tags: android, android-appcompat, material-design, shareactionprovider

I have `android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider` menu in my ActionBar.

When I click "Share", the app list appears as a popup menu.

When I click "Share" in Google Play Newsstand, the app list appears as a bottom sheet that can be pulled up.

Can we configure `ShareActionProvider` from `appcompat-v7` to display bottom sheet instead of popup menu? Are there any alternative `ShareActionProvider` with bottom sheet around?

I found a lib https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet. It gives an idea how to re-implement the ShareActionProvider with bottom sheet. Unfortunately it looks like the lib is missing 'swipe up to pull up' at this moment. And more over, I still have to resolve intents, handle screen rotations and support all the Android versions... Shouldn't this be included in `appcompat-v7`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to use `Intent.createChooser` instead of `ShareActionProvider`.
It gives exactly the same experience as sharing an article from Google Newsstand on Android 5.0.

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, ...);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getString(R.string.item_share)));
```